# ASP.Net 4.5 Web Forms routing works for a while then breaks. Why?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm using the below code in the Global.asax:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}

protected void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.MapPageRoute("APIRoute", "{appId}/{key}/{method}/", "~/handler.aspx");
}
```

At first when I deploy it, and for a couple of minutes after that, the code works for the following sample request:

```
http://localhost/app1/4/em9tcRqT+BZmdIV0YIa5of6i2Jb9zLpWB6WwtVzy3zU=/testFN/?param=46
```

At first the request works and returns results, a few minutes later it starts throwing a 404 Not Found error.

I tried adding the following module through web.config but it didn't help

```
<system.webServer>
<modules>
  <add name="UrlRoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
</modules>
</system.webServer>
```

I'm running ASP.net 4.5 on a Windows 2008 R2 Server
Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: I noticed the error stops for a few minutes when I redeploy the executables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The project was built on an older version of visual studio. All I did to fix this was copy all the source files to a new project under Visual Studio 2013. It works fine now